# Border-left,Border-right etc for android?

Tags: android, styles

I want to style a button in my android app, and I would like to have different colors for each border-side/"stroke-side".. is this possible, or would I need to create a 9patch for this..there aint anything equal to border-left and such as in css?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it before and I couldn't achieve it without using the [NinePatchDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html). I even tried using [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) but you can't apply different colors for different stroke sides.

You can [follow these steps](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) to generate a 9-patch drawable.